# How to execute code whenever a Stripe session has been paid

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to integrate payments in my e-commerce website and Django as a web framework and I would like to create a custom administration site to manage the store, therefore I want to create a Command model whenever a stripe session has been paid.

```py
from .models import Command # I have a Command model

class CommandView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price': 'some price id',
                        'quantity': 1,
                    },
                ],
                mode='payment',
                success_url='http://localhost:3000/success/{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url='http://localhost:3000/store',
                billing_address_collection='auto',
            )
            if checkout_session['payment_status'] == 'paid':
                # this will never work because the status in this view is always unpaid
            return Response({'url': checkout_session['url']})
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'error': e})
```

The solution I found is to execute the code in the `success_url` view but I'm wondering if it's possible to pay and to avoid getting into this url like immediately closing the tab...
And maybe my solution of creating a Command model to see details of a command in the administration like color of product... is wrong, can you give some advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to achieve this is through [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). [This guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) on fulfilling orders is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Ajax to call your view function and handle it using JQuery / Javascript.

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337731/using-the-django-url-tag-in-an-ajax-call) may be able to help you further.

Comment: Yes I've stated this but as I said I don't know if it's secure because you can complete the stripe checkout form and then you close the tab immediately before you are redirected to the success page and the ajax request is not called anymore.

Comment: Then i would recommend @codename_duchess' answer, with webhooks.